# How to insert a working HTML button in an email sent by using Powershell script to Outlook

Tags: javascript, php, html, oracle, powershell

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)

$Mail.To = "email1"
$Mail.Recipients.Add("email2)
$Mail.Subject = "New Request"
$Mail.HTMLBody = " <input type='button' name='approve' value='Submit'/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp <input type='button' name='reject' value='Submit'/> <br/>"
$Mail.HTMLBody += "Kindly approve/reject the request

$Mail.Send()
```

By this script i am not able to display buttons in outlook email properly. But when opened in internet explorer button works fine.

I would also like to know after getting the button how to make it work such that clicking it send the value in the name to database

I want that when i click any of these buttons a Php runs and and column of a table in the database gets updated on clicking the button. What and where should i write the php and database[sql or oracle] script in the above code

Basically i want to have a approve/reject button for a request in email generated by Powershell and the response is then sent to database.

Php code that adds data in my db:

```
   <?php

          if(isset($_POST['submit']))
           {
             $connection = @oci_connect("username","password","db_name");
             $badge= $_POST['BADGE'];
             $_SESSION["badge"]=$badge;
             $reason = $_POST['REASON'];
             $dateFrom = $_POST['DATEFROM'];
             $dateTo = $_POST['DATETO'];
             $dd = $_POST['DD'];
             $backup = $_POST['BACKUP'];
             $employeeName = $_POST['EMPLOYEENAME'];
             $daterequested = date("Y/m/d");

             $_SESSION['datefrom'] = $dateFrom;
             $_SESSION['dateto'] = $dateTo;

             $main_query=oci_parse($connection,"INSERT INTO LEAVEINFO(BADGE,EMPLOYEENAME,TOL,DATEFROM,DATETO,DATEREQUESTED,STATUS,COMMENT1,BACKUP,REASON,LEAD) VALUES('$badge','$employeeName','$dd','$dateFrom','$dateTo','$daterequested','pending','','$backup','$reason','pending')");
                                                                      oci_execute($main_query,OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)

$Mail.To = "Example1@address.com"
$Mail.Recipients.Add("Example2@address.com")
$Mail.Subject = "New Request"

$linkSubmit = "http://www.example.com/"
$linkReject = "http://www.example2.com/"

$html = @"
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> 
    <tr> 
    <td align="center" width="100" height="40" bgcolor="#000091" style="-webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; color: #ffffff; display: block;">
        <a href="$linkSubmit" style="font-size:16px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height:40px; width:100%; display:inline-block"><span style="color: #FFFFFF">Submit</span></a>
    </td> 
    </tr> 
</table> 
<br/>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> 
<tr> 
    <td align="center" width="100" height="40" bgcolor="#000091" style="-webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; color: #ffffff; display: block;">
        <a href="$linkReject" style="font-size:16px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height:40px; width:100%; display:inline-block"><span style="color: #FFFFFF">Reject</span></a>
    </td> 
</tr> 
</table> 
<p>Kindly approve/reject the request</p>
"@

$Mail.HTMLBody = $html
$Mail.Send()
```

This will give you 2 working buttons you will need to change both (`$linkSubmit` `$linkReject`) variables to your database URL.

Tip: Using the `@` operator you can span your `HTML` string over multiple line making it easy to see what your doing.

Ref:[Button CSS](http://www.industrydive.com/blog/how-to-make-html-email-buttons-that-rock/)

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Can you also help me one thing.

@Chard
I want that when i click any of these buttons a Php runs and and column of a table in the database gets updated on clicking the button. What and where should i write the php and database[sql or oracle] script in the above code

Comment: can you also please elaborate on the term Database URL.
Actually i am not able to understand that. I am using Oracle database with a website on localhost. I am using Php as server side language.

Comment: Can you provide all of the code that adds the data into your database that works in IE?

Comment: Database insertion code has been added. And it works in IE also along with chrome and other browsers.